# How do we create generic object where the type of the object is a variable in java?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, dagger

I have a map like this - `Map<Class<? extends Entity>, Config<? extends Entity>> entityClassToConfigMap`

Entries in this class are like: `<EntityA.class, Config<EntityA>>` where EntityA extends Entity. Now I want to iterate over this map and based on the keys in the map I want to create more generic objects like:

```
switch (entityKey.class) {
   case (EntityA.class):
       return Repository<EntityA>
    case (EntityB.class):
       return Repository<EntityB>
...
}
```

I know switch cannot work like that. Is there any other alternative? I am using dagger for dependency injection so also tried building providers using @IntoMap and @ClassKey but that too doesn't work.

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Type parameters are really just information for the compiler.  They cease to exist at run time.  In other words, `return new Repository<EntityA>();` and `return new Repository<EntityB>();` would actually both return the exact same thing.

Comment: You'll need to show more context. What are you actually trying to do? Is `Config` a concrete class? Why is it not responsible for creating a suitable `Repository`?

Comment: And is `return Repository<EntityA>` meant to be `return new Repository<>()`?